# Netbeans SCSS file autocomplete just like CSS file

Tags: netbeans, autocomplete, sass

I am wondering if i can use same autocomplete feature which .css file has in .scss file in netbeans. 
scss file plugin which netbeans has gives nice coloring but doesn't seems to work for autocomplete. 
Is there a ways i can use css like autocomplete for scss file?

Answer (score 3):

there is a scss plugin for Netbeans. http://code.google.com/p/scss-editor/

The newest version (scss-editor 1.1.1 beta) supports autocomplete for scss files.

Comment: Can you pls post the plugin install process and working successfully for netbeans 7.4.

I installed this plugin, but cant compile. Also error in setting scss file path.

Comment: I did not test it yet, but it says it's for Netbeans 7.3, so it might not work with 7.4. In Netbeans 7.4 you have default support for Scss/Sass and Less, which to be honest can be a pain to work with. Read more: http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeans_74_NewAndNoteworthy#CSS_Preprocessors